# Calculating Pi using GMP

Tags: c, gmp, pi

I'm trying to calculate Pi using [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)(5.1.0) with this series:
[image: Pi = 3 + 4 / (2 * 3 * 4) - 4 / (4 * 5 * 6) + 4 / (6 * 7 * 8) - ...]

**What i have done is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

mpz_t pi;
mpz_t next; // Every number in the serie that comes after 3

int a = 2, b = 3, c = 4; // Divisors. Everytime add 2 to all of them at the end of the loop
int i; // Loop counter

int main (void) {
    mpz_init (pi); mpz_init (next);
    mpz_set_str (pi, "3", 10);

    for (i = 2 ;; ++i) {
        printf ("%s\n", mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, pi));

        mpz_set_d (next, 4 / (a * b * c));

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            mpz_add (pi, pi, next);
        else
            mpz_sub (pi, pi, next);

        a += 2; b += 2; c += 2;
    }

    mpz_clear (next);
    mpz_clear (pi);
}
```

**I'm compiling on 64 bit Linux:**

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -o foo foo.c -lgmp
```

**Output:**

```
3
3
3
and so on
```

**Expected Output:**

```
3
3.1666...
3.1333...
3.1452...
3.1396...
and so on
```

---

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: You are doing all these calculations using big integers, and printing out an integer value. Where do imagine the decimal values are going to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do integer division:

```
mpz_set_d (next, 4 / (a * b * c));
//               ^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
//              int      int
```

Dividing two integers will round them towards zero, which is `0` in this case, since `a * b * c > 4` in every iteration.

You *could* fix this by writing

```
mpz_set_d (next, 4.0 / (a * b * c));
//               ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
//             double      int
```

However, you should perform the division using GMP since the code above suffers from the limits of the native number types. Also, the result of this division shouldn't be stored in a GMP integer, but in a GMP float:

```
mpf_t next;
//...
mpf_set_d(next, 4.0);
mpf_div(next, a);
mpf_div(next, b);
mpf_div(next, c);
```

Note that also a, b, c have to be GMP floats in order to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely on this line:

```
mpz_set_d (next, 4 / (a * b * c));
```

On this line you're essentially passing 0 to the `mpz_set_d` function, which I assume sets your number.

That's because you are evaluating `4 / (a * b * c)` using integer arithmetic. `(a * b * c)` is always greater than `4`, so this expression always evaluates to 0. This is *not* what you want.

You should probably put `4` and `(a * b * c)` into two separate GMP floating point numbers and use the GMP functions to do the divison, the treat the result as your `next` variable.

**EDIT:** Looking at GMP documentation, the `mpz` family of functions deals with integers. You probably need to use the `mpf` functions, that deal with floats, or the `mpq` functions, that deal with rationals.

Answer (score 0):

`4 / (a * b * c)` is always zero.

Comment: true, but looks funny as a standalone statement ;-) I'd recommend adding "because a,b and c are integers".